# Getting a gnuplot output from a script

Tags: gnuplot

I have a script that closes immediately after opening. I've tried pause -1, but then I have an empty window. I've also tried set output but apparently I can't do that with multiplot

Is there a way to set output while using multiplot?
I tried setting output before setting multiplot, but the ps file was blank

Edit: The solution I found most useful was "pause mouse". I was also told I could use set output and just do "plot file1, file2, file3", but I'm having some issues with the syntax for that.

Comment: Does using `gnuplot -persist` or `set wxt persist` help?

Answer (score 2):

I typically set the output (and terminal) before going in multiplot mode.  One thing you may be noticing is that some terminals don't draw the plots in a multiplot until you `unset multiplot` (see `help multiplot`).

The following works.

```
set term post enh color
set output "foo.ps"
set multiplot layout 2,1
plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)
unset multiplot
```

One issue with multiplot is that often you want to see the plot (e.g. using x11) and also put it in a file (e.g. postscript).  The cleanest way to do this is using the `load` command:

```
#foo.gp
set multiplot layout 2,1
plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)
unset multiplot
```

Now you can call this:

```
set term x11 persist
load "foo.gp"
set term post enh color
set output 'foo.ps'
load 'foo.gp'
```